# IIS Issue: Default Application Pool not starting after deploying code in IIS using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, iis, powershell-2.0

I am trying to launch Amazon EC2 windows server 2008 R2 instance using AWS Auto Scaling feature. I have used customized AMI in Autoscaling Launch configuration to launch an instance. I have placed PowerShell script in AMI.

The responsibility of script is to download code from AWS S3 and deploy in IIS server while windows startup first time.

When I check status, IIS is started successfully. But default Application pool is not started.

To resolve this issue I have written one scheduled script. It helps to start the application pool if any application pool is in stopped state.

**Scheduled Script:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Import-Module WebAdministration
cd IIS:/AppPools
$ApplicationPools = dir
foreach ($item in $ApplicationPools)
{
    $ApplicationPoolName = $item.Name
    $ApplicationPoolStatus = Get-WebAppPoolState $ApplicationPoolName
    if($ApplicationPoolStatus.Value -eq "Stopped")
    {
         #Write-Host $ApplicationPoolName --&gt; $ApplicationPoolStatus.Value
         Write-Host $ApplicationPoolName "found stopped."
         Start-WebAppPool -Name $ApplicationPoolName
         Write-Host $ApplicationPoolName "started."
    }
}
```

Application pool is started but still i am not able to communicate with IIS server through browser. This all happens when i launch EC2 instance first time.

**IIS Error:**

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

**Note:** As soon as I log on into VM as administrator and wait few minutes problem disappear automatically without doing anything.

Comment: what was the code of the script?

Comment: @user3726488 - When you say it happens only the first time how did you overcome it during subsequent attempt? You had to restart app pool? If it is not working at all then you may need to check for the identity with which it runs. Also did you check the event viewer for any any application/system error?